# Replace all & with &amp; only if not followed by amp;

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, entities

Ok, i'm not that smart in regexp, here's what i'm simply trying to do

basically, i have a string with some already encoded entities, but i need to also encode ALL entities again EXCEPT the `&amp;` entity, so if we have a string

```
The Sun &amp; Mars are planets
```

It will stay the same, because we don't need to encode `&` in `&amp;` again

But if we'll have

```
The Sun &mdash; big hot planet
```

This should become

```
The Sun &amp;mdash; big hot planet
```

I know it's silly, but that's what one parser wants..

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just do two substitutions:

1. Replace `&amp;` with `&`
2. Replace `&` with `&amp;`

Comment: omg now i really need to sleep.. this really solves the issue i have, and no regexp needed, thanks!

Comment: No worries, it happens to the best of us. Feel free to upvote and click the checkmark if this was helpful for you :-)

Answer (score 9):

You can use negative lookahead to match "&" not followed by "amp;".

```
$str = preg_replace( "/&(?!amp;)/", "&amp;",  $str  );
```

Comment: this one is good too, i was searching for a way to do that negative lookahead, but basic manual doesn't describe it.. now i know it!

Comment: This works, though regex is definitely slower than string replacement :-)

Answer (score 0):

Mmm i think that the best way to solve this is using the php function htmlspecialchars, here its the [manual page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) . Basically you will need to disable doble_encode (put a false on it) so that already existing html entities are not parsed again.

Comment: no this does not work if you already have an encoding issue that exist between html tags for example.  The two solutions above will actually fix the issue.  Once the issue is resolved you could then use htmlspecialchars for further encoding...